# Getting current product custom attribute on aroundExecute of Cart Add function - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need to access a custom attribute of the current product in `Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart`. I have tried getting this from the request param, checkoutSession,registry (eventhough its deprecated) but failed.

Is this possible? Following is my code,

```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

    class Add
    {
        /**
         * @var ObjectManagerInterface
         */
        protected $objectManager;

        /**
         * @var RedirectFactory
         */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;
    protected $request;
    protected $registry;
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     *
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface          $objectManager
     * @param RedirectFactory                 $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param UrlInterface                    $url
     * @param RequestInterface                $request
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        UrlInterface $url,
        RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $_checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * Around cart execute
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject
     * @param \Closure                              $proceed
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $cartData = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $cartDataCount = count($cartData);
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
        $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
        $logger->info('-------------------------------Test------------------------');
        $logger->info($cartDataCount);
        $logger->info($product->getId());
        $logger->info($product->getName());
        $logger->info(var_dump($this->request->getParams()));

        $contactUrl = $this->url->getUrl(
            'contact'
        );
        $result = [];
        $result['backUrl'] = $contactUrl;

        $subject->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
        );
        return;
    }
}
```

FYI, I am aware that use of ObjectManager is discouraged. This was done for for testing purpose only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get current Add to cart request path of the product then you have to use request param `product` .magento send product id as a parameter to add to `Add.php`.

```
    protected function _initProduct()
{
    $productId = (int)$subject->getRequest()->getParam('product');
    if ($productId) {
        $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get(
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class
        )->getStore()->getId();
        try {
            // productRepository instead of \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
            return $this->productRepository->getById($productId, false, $storeId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**`_initProduct`** function provide product object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using one of the events for the cart this should make updating information easier.

**Events**

- checkout_cart_add_product_complete
- checkout_cart_update_item_complete
- checkout_cart_product_add_after
- checkout_cart_update_items_before
- checkout_cart_update_items_after
- checkout_cart_save_before
- checkout_cart_save_after
- checkout_cart_product_update_after